# Typescript default optional value

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the correct way to write the following function:

```
function myFunction(group_expr)
```

Where:

- The type is `string` or `bool`
- The field is optional
- The default value is `True`

I've been using this as a reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html.

But it doesn't include all three of those together that I can find. My thinking was something along the lines of:

```
function myFunction(group_expr?: string | bool = true)
```

Comment: Does it not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. That would be done like this:

```
function myFunction(group_expr: string | boolean = true)
```

There's no `?`, because the presence of a default value already makes it optional. And maybe this was just a typo, but it's `boolean` instead of `bool`.